# error while executing didSelectRowAt with tableView.beginUpdates() tableView.endUpdates()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Using [Folding Cell](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell) framework along with [PaginatedTableView](https://github.com/salmaanahmed/PaginatedTableView) framework which seems to be working fine with 20-40 rows. when I'm tapping the cell it opens/closes without any problem, but while scrolling down data comes --> tapping on the cell throws below error
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (80) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (60), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

I'm setting value for cellheight, while loading the data from api

```
self.cellHeights = (0..<self.myNewsList.count).map{ _ in C.CellHeight.close }
 var cellHeights: [CGFloat] = []
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TableViewCell.")
    }
    let durations: [TimeInterval] = [0.26, 0.2, 0.2]
    cell.durationsForExpandedState = durations
    cell.durationsForCollapsedState = durations
    return cell
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}`
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard case let cell as FoldingCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else {return}
    if cell.isAnimating() { 
        return
    }
    var duration = 0.0
    let cellIsCollapsed = self.cellHeights[indexPath.row] == C.CellHeight.close
    if cellIsCollapsed {
        self.cellHeights[indexPath.row] = C.CellHeight.open
        cell.unfold(true, animated: true, completion: nil)
        duration = 0.5
    } else {
        self.cellHeights[indexPath.row] = C.CellHeight.close
        cell.unfold(false, animated: true, completion: nil)
        duration = 0.8
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
         if cell.frame.maxY > tableView.frame.maxY {
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }, completion: nil)

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard case let cell as FoldingCell = cell else {
        return
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    if cellHeights[indexPath.row] == C.CellHeight.close{
        cell.unfold(false, animated: false, completion: nil)
    } else {
        cell.unfold(true, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I think while tapping the `didSelectRowAt`

`tableView.beginUpdates()`

`tableView.endUpdates()`

> getting error 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.'

Comment: You need to check your asynchronous load function -  Because you are using `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` to fold/unfold the cell you are triggering a call to `numberOfRows`- The data source array has changed but you haven't yet called `insertRows`.  Adding `beingUpdates` to your data fetch may fix the problem or you may need to fetch asynchronously to a temporary array and then append all items to the actual array, again using `beginUpdates`/`insertRows`/`endUpdates`

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates) say:

> Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and
>   selection operations (for example, cellForRow(at:) and
>   indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be animated simultaneously. You can also
>   use this method followed by the endUpdates() method to animate the
>   change in the row heights without reloading the cell. This group of
>   methods must conclude with an invocation of endUpdates(). These method
>   pairs can be nested. If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and
>   selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count
>   might become invalid.

Since you do nothing between `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`, table attributes such as row count might become invalid. This might be your problem.

Comment: what can be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after adding  below code at the bottom of didSelectRowAt

`let section = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
tableView.reloadSections(section, with: .none)`

this works well without crashing but animation doesn't work as per [FoldingCell](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell) animation